# Read Excel file with CSV Data Set Config Element

Tags: jmeter

I'm building a project on JMeter and I would like to read an Excel file with CSV Data Set Config to avoid to use Groovy to read it.

Do you know if it is possible? If not, any other JMeter element can help me to read Excel file row by row?

Many thanks in advance,

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) **is only able to read text files**, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> A comma-separated values (CSV) file is a delimited **text** file that uses a comma to separate values.

If your data file is a binary file like [.xls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Binary) or [.xslx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#XML_Spreadsheet) unfortunately CSV Data Set Config won't help, you have the following options:

1. [Export .xls or .xlsx file to CSV](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) using [MS Excel](https://office.live.com/start/excel.aspx) or equivalent
2. If for any reason you cannot use point 1 you can go for [Apache POI libraries](https://poi.apache.org/) to read the Excel file formats in JSR223 Test Elements like it's described in [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test) article.

   You can also see [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) for some code snippets for popular user scenarios when it comes to reading/writing data from/to Excel files